# React restClient admin-on-rest

Tags: json, rest, reactjs, admin-on-rest

[admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest)  allows consuming of any JSON response by writing custom rest clients. The examples in the documentation are for consuming JSON from json-server [project](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)   which is straightforward.

I was wondering how easy is it to consume [this api](http://api.randomuser.me/?results=5) in admin-on-rest with minor changes to [restClient](http://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html).

Comment: It seems your links are pointing to an error page

Comment: Yes even for me link not working. Do chuck the links that you have posted in question

Comment: They released the 0.4.0 version with updated documentation. I've updates the links and fixed the syntax issues with displaying links

Answer (score 0):

Okay - let us look into sources of admin on rest (file admin-on-rest/src/util/fetch.js) we are intrested in fetchJson method.

That method return fetch promise, in which it try to parse json in that code:

```
try {
  json = JSON.parse(body);
} catch (e) {
  // not json, no big deal
}
```

and then it returns that: `return { status, headers, body, json };`
But we have body in result and may reuse it or we may use parsed object in json

For your example we may do so (some code missed):

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    options.withCredentials = true;
        return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options).then(({status, headers, body, json}) => {
        json = json['results'] ? json['results'] : json;
        return {status, headers, body, json};
    });
}
```

So we just overrwrited json object by collection from 'results' in your schema in that line:
`json = json['results'] ? json['results'] : json;`
Now you may use that client in Admin

```
<Admin restClient={restClient}>
...
</Admin>
```

WARNING!!! That will affect to ALL requests of Admin. But you may add additional parameter. If you do not want to use `json = json['results'] ? json['results'] : json;` you may add additional parameter or check in method fetch

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/dev-family/admiral
It's just recently launched, but it's already proven to be a good thing. I think it should help you to solve you problems.

Answer (score -1):

if i am not mistaken, you want to have a rewrite of the url from (as example):
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/customers/684
TO: 
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/?customers=684

you can rewrite the GET_ONE in restClient.js:
   case GET_ONE:
       url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
    TO:
  case GET_ONE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/?${resource}=${params.id}`;

THis will retreive the record via a paramter instead of the url part.